# Making parsing easier in android EditText

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-edittext

I have an app with a couple of EditTexts. The user leaves on empty and the program calculates the empty variable. This is the onClickListener for the button that initiates it all. I was looking to get all the parsing done before the switch so that I only need to parse ALL entries once and then have a 0 put in for the empty one as this would give an error.

How can I streamline this code?

```
public void buttonCalc() {
    calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pv = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pv_pv);
            fv = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pv_fv);
            r = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pv_r);
            n = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pv_n);
            t = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pv_t);
            answer = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pv_answer);
            //check for fields and choice
            if (pv.getText().toString().equals("")) {emptyfields++;choice = 1;}
            if (fv.getText().toString().equals("")) {emptyfields++;choice = 2;}
            if (r.getText().toString().equals("")) {emptyfields++;choice = 3;}
            if (n.getText().toString().equals("")) {emptyfields++;choice = 4;}
            if (t.getText().toString().equals("")) {emptyfields++;choice = 5;}
            if (emptyfields > 1) {MiscMethods.ErrorToast(1);}
            else{
                emptyfields--;
                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                switch (choice) {
                case 1:// pv
                    double fv1 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double result1 = fv1/(Math.pow(1+(r1/n1),n1*t1));
                    result1 = MiscMethods.rounder(result1, 2);
                    answer.setText(answer_pv + result1);
                    break;
                case 2:// fv
                    double pv2 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double r2 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double n2 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t2 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double result2 = pv2*(Math.pow(1 + (r2 / n2), n2 * t2));
                    result2 = MiscMethods.rounder(result2, 2);
                    answer.setText(answer_fv + result2);
                    break;
                case 3:// r
                    double pv3 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double fv3 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double n3 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t3 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double result3 = ((Math.pow(fv3 / pv3, (1 / (n3 * t3)))) - 1)* n3;
                    result3 = MiscMethods.rounder(result3, 4);
                    answer.setText(answer_r +" "+ result3 + " / " + (result3*100)+"%");
                    break;
                case 4:// n
                    MiscMethods.ErrorToast(2);
                    break;
                case 5:// t
                    double pv5 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double fv5 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double n5 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double r5 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double result5 = (Math.log((fv5 / pv5))) / ((Math.log((1 + (r5 / n5)))) * n5);
                    result5 = MiscMethods.rounder(result5, 2);
                    answer.setText(answer_t +" "+ result5);
                    break;
                default:
                    MiscMethods.ErrorToast(3);
                    break;
                }// switch ends
            }// else ends

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is something like this:

```
//initialise doubles with default 0 value when string is empty
double pvDbl = getDouble(pv);
double fvDbl = getDouble(fv);
//etc
```

and the `getDouble` method could be something like:

```
private static double getDouble(EditText et) {
    if(et.getText().length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0; //default value for invalid entries?
                  //Or maybe show an error message?
    }
}
```

You can then replace your `switch` with `if` statements:

```
if (pvDbl == 0 ) {
    //formula for pv null
} else if (fvDbl == 0) {
    //formula for fv null
} //etc.
```

Note that you also need to deal with `0` entries (in the code I propose, you can't make the differnece between an empty entry `""` and an entry of `"0"`.

Comment: Only additional comment in my answer was to add an onTextChangeListener to each edit text so that you can check if the entries parse to double as the user adds them.

Comment: Thanks to both, and I love the idea of the ChangeListener... surround the field with a red layer or smth when the user types in BS ... :) thanks